# Excel: Find nearest lowest value above current row and return from another column

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2010

I've tried a few different examples with similar scenarios been have not yet had any luck.

I have a flat sitemap (450 pages), which is ordered by hierarchy, with each subsequent child page starting with a right arrow (>), with the number of arrows indicating the page depth. I've added a few columns to my data to make this more clear. I now have the following...

[image: screenshot]

I'm looking for a function that will search the Page Depth column (Col C), take the nearest lowest page depth **above** the current row (since that would correspond to the page parent), and then return the pageId of that row (Col A).

Any thoughts would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `AGGREGATE` function:

```
=AGGREGATE(14,6,(1/($C$2:C2=(C3-1)))*$A$2:A2,1)
```

[image]

Comment: Works great, thank you!